# Progressive page loading in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a large page with quite a few items that are loading.

The biggest problem I have is that I have a table that is loading 3000+ rows, and it is taking a while to get all of the data in.

Here's what I need help with:

1. How do I get the rest of the page to load before the table.
2. While the rest of the page is loading, and even while my large table is loading, how do I display a "loading " message or image.

Any help would be appreciated. I would love to use jquery for this

Comment: if your using jquery's ajax to retrieve the data, you can use $.ajaxStart() to load the message and then once that is complete, show the data. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: You need to look into Pagination.

Comment: Look into `$(...).load()`

Answer (score 0):

one option I like is to use the [jquery blockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to block the table, then do a minimal `setTimeout`, basically putting the action of loading all your table data to the end of the js execution stack, e.g.:

```
$("#myTableId").block({
   onBlock: function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
         mytable.data.costlyLoadFunction();
      },100);
   }
});
```

Note: if your load is a separate ajax request, you shouldn't need the `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use [datatables jquery plugin](http://www.datatables.net). It have a option to create table adding the data by ajax. And lot of features. (paginate, etc.)